# Issue in Magento site after migration to AWS

Tags: magento-1.9, aws

I am new to Magento, I have a task to migrate the Existing website built with Magento to AWS cloud(EC2)

Existing Magento Version - 1.9.1.1. I do not want to Upgrade it, as it is out of our scope of work.

I have Migrated all the source files and Database from old server to EC2 instance, So far so good.

After i point the DNS A record to new IP address, a blank page was showing, further debugged and changed as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35611696/fatal-error-uncaught-error-function-name-must-be-a-string-in-c-xampp-htdocs-e
from

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->$callback[1]();
```

to

```
$out .= $this->getBlock($callback[0])->{$callback[1]}();
```

Web Pages are Partially loading.

Now below lines are getting displayed and Product detailed page is also not working

```
getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?> 
getLayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('banner-block')->toHtml(); ?>
getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?> getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>
```

Please Help in getting this resolved.

New Environment running on  - PHP 7.2/Mysql/Apache

URL : http://viviscal.ae/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you probably have something broken in your template php code.
php tag is behind `<!--`:

```
<!--?php// echo $this--->
getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
```

you need to enable `short_open_tag`  in php.ini to properly load templates.

Comment: Yes it is behind comment. Like Below statements.
<?php// echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
<?php// echo $this->getChildHtml('footer_links') ?>

Comment: I have enabled short_open_tag and restarted Apache... But still i am getting the lines printed and detailed page is not coming

Comment: Adding in php.ini didnt work. So added through HTACCESS and voila Worked like a charm.